# Levain Ratio x Sour

Tags: bread, sourdough, sourdough-starter

I always used the 1:2:2 ratio in preparing the dough, of course, it always gets sourer.

I have doubts about some proportions that I have found in some books, but I cannot find the explanation of why.
1:2:2, 1:1:2, 1:2:3 to 1:4:4 or greater.

What are the characteristics of fermentation and flavor of bread when the proportion of flour and water in the preparation of Levain is increased?

Can you help me?

Comment: In contrast, I barely measure and vary proportions widely and it always comes out bread. This tends to bother people who are sure there's "one true way" but I find that many ways are, in fact, true. But if you have a method you are happy with, stick to it, or experiment and see if you like the variation better, or not.

Comment: In fact, there is no true path, but several, in that we fully agree. The fact is that there are paths that have different "flavors" and experiences, and in general, from experience, there are patterns that indicate what the path will be like.